# Can I set the Windows 7 Explorer default columns for all folders?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I'd like to see the PATH rather than the Folder in the columns of Windows Explorer (Win 7 pro), and I can do that for the open window I have. I can't seem to make it stick for EVERY Explorer window every time a folder is opened, though. But this goes to the issue of default columns I want to see, rather than the ones the Windows developers want me to see. Does anyone know how to force the columns I want to see to always be the default?

Comment: I'll try this method one more time, but it seems not to stick. Thx.

Comment: Hey Allen, I didn't realize that you already tried this method. I retract my close-vote